# SpagoBI - Refresh business model XML

Tags: xml, spagobi

Have been googling like crazy but can't find an answer to this. 
I know one cannot refresh the business model in studio (as of V5.2) and needs to manually rework the business model xml file. Has anyone found an easy workaround or edition tool that can make the process easy and painless?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Other than an XML Editor, there is no workaround and it will not be painless :(